# Pagination Not working - wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, pagination

Pagination on my website not working, everything else is fine, But when i click to go to "/page/2/3/" it shows no page found error.

Website : http://savemoney.16mb.com

Error pages: http://savemoney.16mb.com/page/2/

and currently Front Page set to "Latest Posts" (Not Static Page)

Pagination Code (Frontpage.php):

```
<?php
            // show all coupons and setup pagination
            $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
            query_posts( array( 'post_type' => APP_POST_TYPE, 'post_status' => $post_status, 'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1, 'paged' => $paged ) );
            ?>

            <?php get_template_part('loop', 'coupon'); ?>`
```

Any advice on how to get this pagination working correctly would be appreciated!

Thanks,
T

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `, "add_args" => false` ?

here is more info for that https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/30831

Comment: i put this into the pagination code(i believe i done correctly) and still giving me same error "page not found"